# Why is this bad_alloc exception being thrown?

Tags: c++, bad-alloc

I am completely new to C++ and wanted to try and make a simple generic(not sure if this is proper terminology) array class which would essentially work as arrays in java(mainly for the handy length field).
Here is all the code:

```
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
class Array
{
private:
    T* ar;
public:
    const unsigned int length;

    Array(unsigned int length_) : length(length_), ar(new T[length]) {}
    void insert(unsigned int, T);
    T& get(unsigned int);
    T& operator[](unsigned int);
};

template <typename T> void Array<T>::insert(unsigned int index, T dataToAdd)
{
    if(index>=length)
        {throw -1;}
    ar[index]=dataToAdd;
}

template <typename T> T& Array<T>::get(unsigned int index)
{
    if(index>=length)
        {throw -1;}
    return ar[index];
}

template <typename T> T& Array<T>::operator[](unsigned int index)
    {return this->get(index);}


int main()
{
    std::cout << "main start\n";

    Array<int> nums1=Array<int>(2);
    nums1[0]=4;
    nums1[1]=10;
    std::cout << "length of nums1:" << nums1.length << "\n";    

    Array<int> nums2=Array<int>(2);
    nums2[0]=8;
    nums2[1]=5;
    std::cout << "length of nums2:" << nums2.length << "\n";

    Array<int> nums3=Array<int>(2);
    std::cout << "nums3 created\n";
    nums2[0]=3;
    std::cout << "added to index 0\n";
    nums2[1]=15;
    std::cout << "added to index 1\n";
    std::cout << "length of nums3:" << nums3.length <<"\n";

    std::cout << "main end\n";
}
```

It compiles just fine(using MinGW) but when I run it I get the following output:

```
main start
length of nums1:2
length of nums2:2
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
```

Since the last thing being printed by `cout` is *length of nums2:2* I assume the exception is thrown on the line after: `Array<int> nums3=Array<int>(2);`

What is the reason for this? I can't be out of memory can I?

Comment: Changing the constructor this way worked for me:

    `Array(unsigned int length_) : length(length_), ar(new T[length_]) {}`

Comment: Since you're new: Please *never* use the words "just fine", or "works perfectly". If those words applied, you wouldn't need to post.

Comment: I guess you need to learn about the standard library and discover that this class will not be useful to you. Apart from as a means to learn about the language.

Comment: It worked for me as well, thank you! But, why did it work?

Comment: In addition to the answer, remember that in C++ you should free the memory allocated with `new`. So, your class needs a destructor such as `~Array() { delete[] ar; }`

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I do know that vector exists, this is purely to learn about the language.

Comment: If you would enable warnings for your compiler you'd also get some message about this initialization ordering. Something like this `warning: Array<int>::length will be initialized after [-Wreorder]`

Comment: [This is the closest possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8854435/1322972) I can quickly find. Lightness even goes the extra mile to cite the standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regardless of order on your initialization line, member variables are initialized in the order they are *declared* in the class. Thus this:

```
private:
    T* ar;
public:
    const unsigned int length;
```

means `ar` will be initialized before `length`, so this:

```
Array(unsigned int length_) : length(length_), ar(new T[length]) {}
```

is using `length` before it is constructed. Either change the class decl-order of member variables, or use `length_` in the construction of `ar`.

Comment: The constructor can use `length` just fine.

Comment: @Rapptz as written, no, it can't. It's value is indeterminate. If the order in the class decl is switched (as I said in my answer), *then* it is "just fine", as it will then be initialized *before* `ar`.

Comment: The constructor can refer to `length` and expect a well-defined value if `length` has been initialized. Talk of the constructor is moot since the issue is the initializer list.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan there has to be dozens of dupes for this, if I can find one I'm dropping this and linking it instead. Didn't know how much time the OP had to get an answer.

Comment: Well, so much for dropping it. I can't drop an accepted answer (at least I don't have the brass to do so). Still, I linked [the duplicate I think best matches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8854354/does-the-order-of-base-class-initializers-and-member-variable-initializers-matte). Hopefully future readers pick it up.